# RMI createRegistry delay problem

Tags: java, registry, rmi

I'm experiencing a strange and intermittent problem creating an RMI registry from within the JVM. This code will all be run on an intranet, and the idea is to be able to launch services on a bunch of machines easily.

```
public static <X, Y> void newServer(Function<X, Y> function, String name)
  throws Exception {
  FunctionServer<X, Y> fun = null;
  RemoteFunction<X, Y> stub = null;
  Registry registry = null;
  try {
    fun = new FunctionServer<X, Y>(function);
    stub = (RemoteFunction<X, Y>) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(fun, 0);
  }
  catch (RemoteException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
  }

  boolean foundPort = false;
  int port = 1099;
  do {
    try {
      registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
      registry.rebind(name, stub);
      // Thread.sleep(100);
      foundPort = true;
    }
    catch (ExportException e) {
      port++;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      throw e;
    }
  } while (!foundPort);
  if (registry.lookup(name) != null)
    System.out.println("Service " + name + " serving "
        + function.getClass().getCanonicalName() + " on port " + port);   
}
```

There is of course a very simple main method:

```
FileSystemXmlApplicationContext context =
    new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(args[0]);
Object obj = context.getBean(args[1]);
if (obj instanceof Function<?, ?>) {
  Function<?, ?> fun = (Function<?, ?>) obj;
  FunctionServer.newServer(fun, args[2]);
}
```

The code is invoked from the command line as follows:

```
java -cp daopt.jar -Djava.rmi.server.codebase="file://daopt.jar" ****.*******.remote.FunctionServer spring/rosenbrockServer.xml rosenbrock rosenbrock
```

Sometimes, though, it fails silently. It prints the successful server start message, but then there is no java process running, and netstat -anp | grep [portNumber] shows nothing. Remarkably, if I put in a delay in the newServer method i.e., uncomment the line

```
Thread.sleep(100);
```

it all works fine. Does this mean that LocateRegistry.createRegistry is launching some sort of worker thread that throws an exception after a while? What's going on?

Flummoxed,
Dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the 'registry' variable a static member. At the moment it is being garbage-collected, which unexports it, and allows the server to be DGC'd, which allows the process to exit.

You don't need that do/while loop. Use Registry.REGISTRY_PORT. That's what it's for. Reserved at IANA for the RMI Registry.

Comment: Aha! Good one! Rather than making it static, I made it final. That fixed it. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I still need the port number because there may be other RMI registries on port 1099.

Comment: Make it static. I gave the reasons. Making it final doesn't fix those.

Comment: If you already have an RMI Registry on port 1099 why do you need this one?

Comment: Because it's not the only registry on that machine. And there may be other registries started, and there may not, by other users of that server.

Comment: But why do you think you need multiple Registries?

Comment: While it's possible to get it to work with just one, different people are usually working off different codebases, often with different versions of the same classes as they develop and modify them. And from what I understand, multiple registries would make this easier.

Comment: So how do your clients know which Registry to lookup? Do they loop through the ports too? Pretty hairy design.

Answer (score -1):

When using LocateRegistry.createRegistry within the JVM, it's advisable to use

```
final Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
```

Comment: *Why* is that advisable? First I've heard of that in 12 years of RMI.

Comment: Hmm, if the reason is that it's being GC'ed, making the variable final will prevent that, no? Why make something static if it doesn't need to be? Given that there's only one registry per JVM, it amounts to the same thing, I guess.

Comment: No, making a local variable final *won't* prevent it from being GC'd. Making it static will.